# Android spinner layout 

Tags: android, layout, spinner

I have set a dynamic value in a spinner . I am using following code for the same.

```
spinner_generalbooks.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[]{"Author","ISBN","Keyword","Title"}));
```

It is working fine, but I have a problem with the view of the spinner . If we select `simple_spinner_item`, it is ok in normal state, but when we want to change it, the rows are very narrow and not `CheckedTextView` whereas in normal spinner options comes with `CheckedTextView`. If we select `simple_spinner_dropdown_item`, the options come with `CheckedTextView`, but in normal state, it looks different as in the pic

(First one is default spinner and second one is using `simple_spinner_dropdown_item`).

[image: First one is default spinner and second one is using <code>simple_spinner_dropdown_item</code>]

I want to show the spinner just like as default spinner. How to make it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android will take the layout specified in the adapter and use it for the control and the items unless you specify the view-resource separately. The way through this is to set the layout to **simple_item** in the ArrayAdapter constructor and then set the layout **dropdown_item** separately in a call to setDropDownViewResource().

```
ArrayAdapter newAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[]{"Author","ISBN","Keyword","Title"});

newAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner_generalbooks.setAdapter(newAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you whant to customize the visual of your Spinner, it'll be more simple to create your own component. A spinner is just a Layout that contains text, image and that display a list in a popup. Create a custom layout for your item and use a new BaseAdapter object to bind your datas.

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/

hope i could help

Comment: I do not want any custom one.